# I am unable to figure out why my code throws a TypeError

Tags: python, while-loop, typeerror

I am trying to run a `while` loop which basically detect changes in a website. But when I ever I run the code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/parse.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/parse.py", line 19, in main
    old_data = soup.copy()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
[Finished in 0.461s]
```

Here's my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from functools import partial


def parse(text):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')
    return soup

def main():
    URL = 'https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro-16/'
    session = requests.Session()
    old_data = None
    while True:
        r = session.get(URL)
        new_data = parse(r.text)
        if new_data != old_data:
            print('new_data')
            old_data = new_data.copy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Which line is reported as the one causing the type error? Often when I see this error it indicates that I am calling a function on an item I thought would be populated earlier, but it was not.

Comment: Neither could anyone else looking at this code; please update your question to include the full `Traceback` message which would include all the affected source files that your program triggered.

Comment: I updated the question to include the full traceback message.

Comment: The error message basically says that `soup.copy` is `None`. Looking at the BeautifulSoup docs, I'm unable to find a `copy` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BeautifulSoup doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#copying-beautiful-soup-objects) says:

> You can use copy.copy() to create a copy of any Tag or NavigableString

Could you try

```py
import copy  # should be at top of the file
old_data = copy.copy(new_data)
```

#### Explanation

From BS code:

```py
def __getattr__(self, tag):
        #print "Getattr %s.%s" % (self.__class__, tag)
        if len(tag) > 3 and tag.endswith('Tag'):
            ... # deprecated code
        # We special case contents to avoid recursion.
        elif not tag.startswith("__") and not tag == "contents":
            return self.find(tag)
```

What happens?

`new_data.copy` is the same as `new_data.find('copy')` and return None (there is no `<copy>` tag).

Than you do this:

```py
old_data = new_data.find('copy')()
```

Comment: It worked but I don't know why `new_data.copy()` did not work.